# Using polar coordinates to evaluate multivariable integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

The prompt is to evaluate the integral $\iint_D|x-y|\,dx\,dy$ where $D= \{(x, y) \in R^2 : x \ge 0, 0 \le y \le 3-2x \}$

Plotting the graph for the region looks something like this

[image]

Looking at the graph we can tell, 
 $$\int_0^{3}\int_{0}^{3-2x}|x-y|\,dx\,dy$$

Is this the correct way to evaluate limits? What are we supposed to do with the modulus?

Comment: The region does not look like that at all. It is a quarter of a disk.

Comment: break into two integrals

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
As you have a mod inside the integral, you need to get rid of it. On the drawing that you have made, also draw the line $x-y=0$. This will divide your region into two halves; without the mod. Calculate area of both the regions and then add them. Try it, if you still have trouble, comment below.